# Mouse clicking issues

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I finally got ubuntu 12.04 installed after figuring out what the problem was.

For some reason, mouse clicks aren't always registered correctly so I had to use the arrows, tab and space to select and change options.

Now in ubuntu I got the same problem. The mouse moves around perfectly, and in the active window I can do everything but it's a real pain to get something else clicked outside of that window.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the terminal, run `xev` which is in the `x11-utils` package. This will show you the window inside which you can click and test your mouse buttons and make sure the X server is indeed receiving those events which will be shown in the terminal window from which you started `xev`.